# How to print multi-line progress list in console

Tags: java

I just write a method to print a progress bar in console. It can print like this：

[>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>=====================================]

```
public void progress(int percent){
    System.out.print('\r');
    String progressText = "[" + StringUtils.repeat(">", percent) + StringUtils.repeat("=", 100-percent) + "]";
    System.out.print(progressText);
}
```

But it can only work in single thread and single line.
Is there any way to print multilines by multithreads like
Thread-1: [>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>=====================================]
Thread-2: [>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>==================================]

**I want it like the progress lines of `yum install xxx -y` in centos.**
**Is it possible?**

Comment: [synchronize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) the method, or refactor so that the string is built first and only one `System.out.print` is used.

Comment: do a single call to `System.out.print` with the complete string

Comment: @Michael How will the progress on multiple threads work symoultaneously if you block one of the threads? The edit seems more wrong to me. What is the point of having a single print if you want to visualize real time progress?

Comment: @NiVeR They will just take turns

Comment: I edit the code. The problem is that there is always only one line in consle. I want mulit lines show in console.

Comment: default console is multiline. please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ansi escape codes for this.  There's a small library that has them all baked in.  Here is a very terse example that should allow you to easily see how the codes work.

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    System.out.print(Ansi.cursorUp(5));

    int v = i;
    if (i % 3 == 0) v *= 100;
    if (i % 10 == 0) v *= 1000;
    if (i % 21 == 0) v *= 1000000;

    System.out.print(Ansi.cursorDown());
    System.out.print(Ansi.eraseLine());
    System.out.printf("\rone %s", v + 5);

    System.out.print(Ansi.cursorDown());
    System.out.print(Ansi.eraseLine());
    System.out.printf("\rtwo %s", v + 1);

    System.out.print(Ansi.cursorDown());
    System.out.print(Ansi.eraseLine());
    System.out.printf("\rthree %s", v + 9);

    System.out.print(Ansi.cursorDown());
    System.out.print(Ansi.eraseLine());
    System.out.printf("\rfour %s", v + 15);

    System.out.print(Ansi.cursorDown());
    System.out.printf("\r");

    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

The Maven coordinates for the library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.tomas-langer.cli</groupId>
  <artifactId>cli-progress</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: only show one line

Answer (score 0):

you can make your method `synchronized` and use `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to print name of the thread calling this method:

```
public void synchronized progress(int percent){
    System.out.print('\r');
    String progressText = Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": [" + 
    StringUtils.repeat(">", percent) + StringUtils.repeat("=", 100-percent) + "]";
    System.out.print(progressText);
}
```

This will ensure that your information would be printed consistently in respect to each other.

Comment: synchronizing this method is a bit overkill, you can simply build the complete string and call print once

Comment: @jhamon there is no guarantees that `System.out.println` is threadsafe. you will anyway need to synchronize this line, so I just simplified and made synchronization on method, which doesnt have lots of logic inside, so there wouldn't me much difference. Yes, currently openjdk/hotspot implementations are thread safe, but there are no guarantees regarding that, as it's undocumented details of implementation